# How to pass a list(subject, point) to a class Student in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to pass to a Student class that looks like this:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName,subject,points) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.points = points;   
}
```

an array of (subject, grades), so that I can keep for every student his grades.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like you should redesign your Student class. Instead of just one subject and grade, it should have an array that contains a list of `{subject, grade}` objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot's of ways of doing that. One of them is:

```
var student = {};
student.firstName = 'a';
student.lastName = 'b';
student.subject = 'c';
student.points = 'd';
student.extraInfo = [{subject:'math', grade:'90'},{subject:'english', grade:'88'}];
```

another way is:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName,subject,points) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.points = points; 
    this.extraInfo = [{subject:'math', grade:'90'},{subject:'english', grade:'88'}]  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an object,
For eg:

```
var courses = {math: 88, science: 90};
```

This is if you already know what subjects to expect, and so the subject name can become the key, and the grade can be the value.

If you dont know the subject names, then you can pass in a list of objects, in which case courseList can look like something like this:

```
var courseList = [{subject: 'math', grade: 88}, {subject: 'science', grade: 90}];
```

Your class structure now becomes:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName, subject, points, courseList) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.points = points; 
    this.subjects = courseList ;
}
```

And since you already know what keys to expect, you can traverse through subjects to retrieve the relevant information.